# create windows folder shortcut using java? Note: not using symboliclink

Tags: java, window, shortcut

I have to create a window folder shortcut using java.
For example,

```
C:\Foldername
```

I have to create a shortcut using this path

```
C:\FolderName-shortcut
```

Like we create shortcuts in desktop

I don't want to create a desktop shortcut. I have to create a folder shortcut within the folder

Comment: You need to use a native interface/library, java itself isn't capable of doing that.

Comment: @BackSlash please provde me library for JShellLink and i dont want to create desktop shortcut.Create Folder shortcut as i said in example C:\foldername

Comment: Read question and answer, they have all the links.

Comment: ok @BackSlash got it!!

Comment: @BackSlash i have use this code and it will create desktop shortcut but i want a folder shortcut within that folder. I have tried all the way by passing path of different like c:\foldername but neither it give me error nor it will create folder on that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help @BackSlash after passing path directly to setFolder it has resolve my problem.before i have passing path to setdirectory method inside setfolder so it will not create the path.